# ASP net MVC5 "view validation if only routed from another controller not by typing in address bar"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have controller where inside are 2 methods , the validation is a code, if it is correct then call the another method in different controller, but there is a problem if someone write in the address bar the controller for example home/sdata/display then it retrieve the data without writing the password(code) how can i prevent to display the data until he writes the code

```
    public ActionResult predata() 
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult prerest(string paswd)
    {
        if (paswd == "123456852")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("sdata","displays");

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the validation check in the `sdata` Controller's `displays` method. If the password not right, redirect to some other page or just display an empty view.

Comment: i tried that but the only problem when it sends the password to another actionmethod the password shows in the address bar any idea how can i hide it ?? i have used return redirecttoaction("sdata","display", new {paswd}) , how can i make it hidden in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

If you add [Authorize] this problem will not exist. Probably you made something wrong with authorization. You should check more about authorization patterns for example **Token Based Authentication - OWIND** etc.

Comment: i have wrote authorize above the actionmethod but the project still without user name and password so am just developing that.